# cannot upgrade vulkan

Tags: amdgpu, vulkan

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with AMD Radeon R9 390 gpu.
Graphics driver: AMD gpu-pro 17.10  (The latest driver is 17.40)

I have previously installed vulkan. But whenever I try to install a newer version it does not update.

I have just now downloaded and install LunarG Vulkan sdk 1.0.61.1

But when I prompt "vulkaninfo" I get the following:

```
Vulkan API Version: 1.0.42

INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/simon/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/simon/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /etc/vulkan/icd.d/amd_icd64.json, version "1.0.0"
WARNING: [loader] Code 0 : loader_icd_scan: ICD JSON /etc/vulkan/icd.d/amd_icd64.json does not have an 'api_version' field.
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /etc/vulkan/icd.d/amd_icd32.json, version "1.0.0"
WARNING: [loader] Code 0 : loader_icd_scan: ICD JSON /etc/vulkan/icd.d/amd_icd32.json does not have an 'api_version' field.
ERROR: [loader] Code 0 : /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/i386-linux-gnu/amdvlk32.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Why does it say 1.0.42 - I have never downloaded that version.

I have tried several times and tried to uninstall. Followed both these guides:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Install-LunarG-Vulkan-SDK.aspx

https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/latest/linux/getting_started.html

Comment: Can nobody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your environment variables in `~/.bashrc` probably aren't set up. Here's how they work for me for SDK 1.0.65.0:

```
export VULKAN_SDK=~/Downloads/VulkanSDK/1.0.65.0/x86_64
export PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

After you have added those lines, restart your Terminal and run `vulkaninfo` again.